# Access Remote Disc across a WAN or two LANs separated by VPN

Tags: vpn, optical-drive, remote-disc

We've used Remote Disc to access a DVD reader attached to one computer on a LAN before. Now that we're all 'work from home', we've got a VPN setup that creates peer-to-peer connections between all of our location and all normal traffic flows fine across it.

However, from my computer, I can't "Remote Disc" to a DVD drive located on another users location which is connected via the VPN. Each 'location' is its own LAN. Example 192.168.2.0/24, 192.168.3.0/24, 192.168.4.0/24, etc

Is there some clever way to make this work. We have a use case where the DVD burner is needed in one location, but reading the disc is required in another.

As of right now when I click "Remote Disc" it only works from a computer on the LAN the DVD burner is attached to. When I click "Remote Disc" from a remote location, nothing shows up even though we're all connected via the VPN network.

Comment: Who manages your VPN? They just need to allow Bonjour traffic across the tunnel for this to work. L2 just works and L3 needs a Bonjour proxy. https://serverfault.com/a/445696

Comment: @bmike had the correct answer. On PepLink routers there was a non-obvious field for setting up Bonjour Forwarding service. Once configured everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@bmike had the correct solution.

On a PepLink Router, under LAN->Network Settings, you need to select Enable the 'Bonjour Forwarding Settings' and then set the Service and Client Pairs. In our case we set a bi-directional pair by selecting the VPN remote as Service/Local LAN as client and the reverse as well with local LAN as Service/VPN remote as client.

You need to also add matching pairs on the opposite end routers.

Many thanks to @bmike for pointing in the right direction.